# Basic Firebase Java connection

Tags: java, firebase

I am trying to make a basic connection to firebase within a Java app, and using the basic code provided I am unable to get any response at all.

Here is the code I am using:

```
package fix;

import com.firebase.client.*;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    String url = "https://----.firebaseIO.com/";
    Firebase dataRef = new Firebase(url);

    dataRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
             System.out.println("data");
         }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled() {
             System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
         }
    });

    System.out.println("hi");
  }
}
```

The library seems to be loading fine. Any suggestions?

**Update**

```
[java] Fri Sep 06 09:54:43 PDT 2013 [DEBUG] ViewManager: Raising events for /.info/authenticated
 [java] Fri Sep 06 09:54:43 PDT 2013 [DEBUG] ViewManager: Doing onDiff with changes: []
 [java] Fri Sep 06 09:54:43 PDT 2013 [DEBUG] ViewManager: Marking queries complete for /.info/authenticated
 [java] Fri Sep 06 09:54:43 PDT 2013 [DEBUG] ViewManager: Marking queries complete for /.info/authenticated
 [java] Fri Sep 06 09:54:43 PDT 2013 [DEBUG] ViewManager: Marking queryMap complete:null
 [java] Fri Sep 06 09:54:43 PDT 2013 [DEBUG] ViewManager: Marking queries complete for /.info/authenticated
 [java] Fri Sep 06 09:54:43 PDT 2013 [DEBUG] ViewManager: Marking queryMap complete:null
 [java] Fri Sep 06 09:54:43 PDT 2013 [DEBUG] ViewManager: Raising events for /.info/connected
 [java] Fri Sep 06 09:54:43 PDT 2013 [DEBUG] ViewManager: Doing onDiff with changes: []
 [java] Fri Sep 06 09:54:43 PDT 2013 [DEBUG] ViewManager: Marking queries complete for /.info/connected
 [java] Fri Sep 06 09:54:43 PDT 2013 [DEBUG] ViewManager: Marking queries complete for /.info/connected
 [java] Fri Sep 06 09:54:43 PDT 2013 [DEBUG] ViewManager: Marking queryMap complete:null
 [java] Fri Sep 06 09:54:43 PDT 2013 [DEBUG] ViewManager: Marking queries complete for /.info/connected
 [java] Fri Sep 06 09:54:43 PDT 2013 [DEBUG] ViewManager: Marking queryMap complete:null
 [java] Fri Sep 06 09:54:43 PDT 2013 [DEBUG] ViewManager: Adding Value Event Listener callback for path: /
 [java] Fri Sep 06 09:54:43 PDT 2013 [DEBUG] PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Listening on / for [{}]
 [java] Fri Sep 06 09:54:43 PDT 2013 [DEBUG] PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Adding listen params: [{}]
 [java] Fri Sep 06 09:54:43 PDT 2013 [DEBUG] EventRaiser: Raising 0 event(s)
 [java] wait
 [java] wait
 [java] wait
 [java] wait
```

Comment: You print "hi" and quit immediately, what would you expect to happen?

Comment: Have you tried writing data to Firebase from your app?  That would verify that the library is correctly installed and everything.

Comment: I did attempt to write and could not. I have not been able to see evidence of a connection at all. To install the library I put the jar in my library and included com.firebase as shown above. Are there any other steps to take? I assumed that since the library objects didn't throw errors that everything was included properly.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I've spent a few hours messing with this myself; not a lot of luck

Comment: I added some logging to try to see what's going on; I tried modifying a child called JavaTest and I get the message:
`DEBUG: Transaction - Aborting transactions for path: /JavaTest. Affected: /JavaTest` so I don't know what that's about.

Comment: I appreciate it. Perhaps the API is meant specifically for Android? I will try to reach out to the Firebase team and see if they have a solution.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem. What might be interesting: I ran your code while monitoring network traffic using wireshark and found out that it's not making a single connection. Unfortunately that's all I can tell right now, but maybe it helps narrowing down the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Engineer here, can you enable logging and post the output? You can enable logging by doing:

```
Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG);
```

Also, can you add an observer for

```
dataRef.child(".info/connected");
```

And log the events that you get from it? That will tell you when you are connected or disconnected from Firebase.

Edit:
This was resolved over email. It was a bug in the client library, which is now resolved. You can download the latest version from the website: https://www.firebase.com/docs/downloads.html

Comment: I updated the question with the resulting logs. Hopefully I captured the logs correctly.

Comment: Hi Derek. Can you email me at greg at firebase.com? I'd like to follow up on this, since the logs aren't showing much. Can you also include the version of the Firebase SDK you're using, as well as your java version? (Firebase.getSdkVersion() and java -version)

Answer (score 4):

I believe the probelm is that, unlike Node.js which keeps running waiting for events and callbacks to fire, Java quits when it reaches the end of the main method.  You'll want to keep the main thread from quitting.  Something like this should keep the main thread from terminating.

```
while(true) {
     Thread.Sleep(10000); //Sleep 10 seconds
}
```

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. The console didn't 'next line', so I assumed it was kept alive. I stuck in the sleep with a println, and it just keeps printing with no response from firebase.